# Radio button on change the active button's Icon should be OutlineIcon or FillledIcon

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="auction-type-filter">
  <li>
    <label class="btn" data-toggle="iconOnOff" data-icon-on="bb-home" data-icon-off="bb-home-o">
      <input type="radio" name="auction-type"> <i class="bbIcon"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="btn" data-toggle="iconOnOff" data-icon-on="bb-setting" data-icon-off="bb-setting-o">
      <input type="radio" name="auction-type"> <i class="bbIcon"></i>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. Once the page loaded data-icon-off="off-icons-o" should be added to
   all `<i class="bbIcon">` eg. `<i class="bbIcon bb-setting-o">`
2. Once radio button clicked the active icon should be added with filled icon `<i class="bbIcon bb-setting">`

Here is my jQuery:

```
var bidderBlockIcon, bbIconOn, bbIconOff;

function fnButtonOutlineOnOff(el) {
  bbIconOn = $(el).attr('data-icon-on');
  bbIconOff = $(el).attr('data-icon-off');
  bidderBlockIcon = $(el).find('.bbIcon');
}

$('[data-toggle="bbIconOnOff"]').each(function () {
  // Adds outline Icons to all <i class="bbIcon"></i>
  fnButtonOutlineOnOff(this);
  bidderBlockIcon.addClass(bbIconOff);
}).click(function () {
  fnButtonOutlineOnOff(this);
  bidderBlockIcon.addClass(bbIconOn);
});
```

The above code just adds filled icon `<i class="bbIcon bb-setting"></i>` but on selecting other radio button doesn't change to `<i class="bbIcon bb-setting-o"></i>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach would be to have a function to turn them all *off*, then turn the `change` radio *on*.

```js
function allOff() {

  $('[data-toggle="bbIconOnOff"]').each(function() {

    var bbIconOn = $(this).data('icon-on');
    var bbIconOff = $(this).data('icon-off');
    $(this).find('.bbIcon').removeClass(bbIconOn).addClass(bbIconOff);

  });

}

$('[name="auction-type"]').change(function() {

  allOff();
  var bbIconOn = $(this).parent().data('icon-on');
  $(this).next('.bbIcon').addClass(bbIconOn);

});

allOff();
```

Answer (score 1):

Set default icon in your HTML.

```
<ul id="auction-type-filter">
 <li>
  <label class="btn" data-toggle="iconOnOff" data-icon-on="bb-home" data-icon-off="bb-home-o"> One
   <input type="radio" name="auction-type">
   <i class="bbIcon bb-home-o"></i>
  </label>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label class="btn" data-toggle="iconOnOff" data-icon-on="bb-setting" data-icon-off="bb-setting-o"> Two
  <input type="radio" name="auction-type">
  <i class="bbIcon bb-setting-o"></i>
 </label>
</li>
```

```
$('input[name=auction-type]').change(function() {
 $('input[name=auction-type]').next().attr('class', '').addClass('bbIcon');
 $(this).next().removeClass($(this).parent().attr("data-icon-off")).addClass($(this).parent().attr("data-icon-on"));
});
```